# How java calls c# in linux

Tags: java, c#, linux

Java can call the .dll generated by c # through JNA in Windows, but JNA can only call the. so file in Linux. I have tried to convert c # into c and then into. so file, but it seems to be impractical. Is there any way for Java to call c # in Linux

Comment: An .so in Linux is essentially the same as a .dll in Windows.  You can use the `--aot` flag to compile C# to a `.so`, but I don't know if that includes code to launch the runtime.

Comment: @TimRoberts Is it using Mono's AOT for conversion?

Comment: Conversion of what?  I'm saying you can use `mono --aot` to compile your C# files to a Linux .so.  I don't know how that plays with Java.